# Creating variable sized arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, dynamic, arraylist

I have been creating arrays for different controls as follows, e.g:

```
private TextBox[] Array_TextBoxes;
private CheckBox[] Array_CheckBoxes;
private RadioButtonList[] Array_radioButton;

Array_TextBoxes= new TextBox[4];
Array_CheckBoxes= new CheckBox[5];
Array_radioButton= new RadioButtonList[10];
```

Is there any ways of creating them so that I do not need to specify the size/length? I.e. is it possible to make these control arrays variable sized?

Thanks!

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Arrays must be assigned a length,  if you want to allow for any number of elements 
use the [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class, like this

```
List<TextBox> textBoxList=new List<TextBox>();
```

and add controls into this collection

```
 textBoxList.Add(new TextBox());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could start them as lists then convert to array:

Add stuff to these using `.Add`:

```
List<TextBox> _TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
List<CheckBox> _CheckBoxes =  new List<CheckBox>();
List<RadioButtonList> _RadioButton = new List<RadioButtonList>();
```

Then convert to arrays:

```
TextBox[] Array_TextBoxes = List<TextBox> _TextBoxes.ToArray();
CheckBox[] Array_CheckBoxes = List<CheckBox> _CheckBoxes.ToArray();
RadioButtonList[] Array_radioButton = List<RadioButtonList> _radioButton.ToArray();
```

Or just use lists...

Answer (score 2):

`List<>`, as others have suggested, is a good idea, but it does have some overhead.  You can also do this, if you "use" System.Linq, and assume that the `controls` variable points to a collection of the controls:

```
Array_TextBoxes = controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();
```

Furthermore, if you prefer to have lists instead of arrays, you can do that too:

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
```

Finally, it's often considered poor style to use prefixes like "Array_" in your field and variable names.